# Update function to Firebase V9 with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have updated my project with version 9 of firebase and I started to have some code errors that I still can't solve.

the previous function looks like this. and I need to update it for the new firebase V9 version

```
const doc = await firebaseApp
  .firestore()
  .collection('documents')
  .doc(params.documento)
  .get();

if (!doc) {
  return {
    notFound: true,
  };
}

const data = doc.data();

return {
  props: {
    texto: {
      ...data,
      fecha: data?.fecha?.toDate().toLocaleString('es-ES', { timeZone: 'UTC', day: '2-digit', month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }),
    },
  },
};
}
```

Comment: Rather than posting your V8 code and just asking someone to translate it to V9 for you, it's probably best to show your attempt at the V9 code and then describe the error(s) that you encountered.

Comment: The Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) has code samples for v8 and v9 syntax, so you can compare them, and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) also outlines the process.

Comment: yes, the error is A required parameter (documento) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /documento/[documento]  

the current code is 

` 
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    const snapshot = await getDocs (collection(db, 'documents')); 
    const paths = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      return {
        params: {id: doc.id.toString()}
      }
    })

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
}



 `

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this problem.

```
    const snapshot = await getDocs (collection(db, 'documents')); 
    const paths = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
      
      return {
        params: {
          documento: doc.id.toString()
        }
      }
    })

    return {
      paths,
      fallback: false
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const documento = context.params.documento;

  const docRef = doc(db, 'documents', documento);
  const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

  return {

    props: {textoProps: JSON.stringify(docSnap.data()) || null}

  }
}
```